NGX Extended Pdf Viewer: Generic Approach for Acrofields?
Is it possible to create a generic solution for the PDF Forms?
In the documentation its shown like this, but here the names of the acrofields and the amount of them is already known
public firstName = 'Jane';
public lastName = 'Doe';
public country = 'Spain';
public jobExperience = '6';
public typeScript = true;

public get formData(): { [fieldName: string]: string | number | boolean } {
return {
firstName: this.firstName,
lastName: this.lastName,
yearsOfExperience: this.jobExperience,
typeScript: this.typeScript,
country: this.country
};
}

public set formData(data: { [fieldName: string]: string | number | boolean }) {
this.firstName = data.firstName as string;
this.lastName = data.lastName as string;
this.jobExperience = data.yearsOfExperience as string;
this.country = data.country as string;
this.typeScript = data.typeScript === 'true' || data.typeScript === true;
}

Is it possible to send a list of strings with the acrofield name and then bind them to this set and get formdata methods? How should I approach this?
Already tried using a map, but whenever i try to assign it in a similar fashion the extension breaks. I feel like this approach is not suitable, any suggestions?

I do use ngxService.getFormData to read all data from an arbitrary PDF Form as documented on the "Forms raw data" tab on this page: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/forms.
It might also be helpful to listen to the formRendered event and then build a map of the HTML input elements associated to the currently rendered form fields:
document.getElementById('pdfjs_internal_id_' + annotation.fieldAnnotation.id) as HTMLInputElement

